# How variables are passed in a Python function?

Tags: python, variables

If I run the following code in Python 2.7, I get [2., 2., 2.] printed for both a and b. Why does b change together with a? Many thanks!

```
def test_f(x):
    a = np.zeros(3)
    b = a
    for i in range(3):
        a[i] += x
    print a
    print b
    return 0

test_f(2)
```

Comment: because a and b refer to the same memory location holding the list

Answer (score 5):

Because `b` and `a` are referring to the same list in memory. `b = a` does not create a new copy of `a`. 
Try this and see the difference:

```
def test_f(x):
    a = np.zeros(3)
    b = a.copy()
    for i in range(3):
        a[i] += x
    print a
    print b
    return 0

test_f(2)
```

`b = a.copy()` will create a **new** copy that exactly resembles the elements of `a`, whereas `b=a` just creates a new reference to the exisiting list.

Comment: I think for readability ``b=a.copy()`` or ``b=np.array(a, copy=True)`` would be better since you explicitly mention that a copy is made.

Comment: Also, you need only one colon between the brackets.

Comment: I agree with @MSeifert; moreover the `[::]` only needs one colon

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I fixed it!

Comment: I agree with MSeifert, but this is an easier way to code anyways... This point is kinda subtle so I guess it will be helpful to mark the "copy" explicitly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

numpy will use a pointer to copy unless you tell it otherwise:

```
import numpy as np

def test_f(x):
    a = np.zeros(3)
    b = np.copy(a)
    for i in range(3):
        a[i] += x
    print a
    print b
    return 0

test_f(2)

[ 2.  2.  2.]
[ 0.  0.  0.]
```

Comment: Thanks, Keith! This is a very clear explanation!